# android Java libgdx text file

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm having some trouble with loading and reading a text file in my android studio project. When I run the desktop version it runs fine but when I run it on my phone (galaxy s4) through adb or packaging the app and manually installing it I get a blank black screen after my splash screens. Through adb my logcat shows

W/System.err: Java.io.FileNotFoundException: /levels/1txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

My file is in the assets folder in a sub folder called levels. The part of the code that flags the error is

String filePath = "levels/1.txt";
File filename = new File(filePath);

The code after this uses scanner to read the file and put the characters in an array.

I do wonder whether its my code thats wrong, my phone or my android studio setup(like it's not including my text file or something silly)

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere. I was looking last night but didn't find anything that helped.

Thanks in advance for any help

Edit: tried it on a different phone and got the same result so presume its a code problem or and android studio project setup error

Comment: Use LibGDX FileHandle instead of File to load files or your code may not work on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

May you try this :

```
FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("levels/1.txt");

String s = new String(fileHandle.readString());

System.out.println(s);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the replies I will give this a try when I get a chance